# Share button is not clickable in Android Webview App

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to add share functionality to my webview app but unable to get it to work properly. I am able to show the icon and there aren't any errors as well but still the share button is not clickable. I am searching for 2 days but got nothing working instead of different tutorials for implementing share functionality. Although this one shows no error but, this just doesn't work.

My Java File

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView YoWeb;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb();
            }
        });
        LoadWeb();
    }

    public void LoadWeb() {
        YoWeb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = YoWeb.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        YoWeb.loadUrl("website url");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        YoWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            //onPageFinished Method
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //Hide the SwipeRefreshLayout
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (YoWeb.canGoBack()) {
            YoWeb.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate menu resource file.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);

        // Return true to display menu
        return true;
    }

    // Call to update the share intent
    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Main Menu Layout File

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.yoalfaaz.yoalfaaz.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `ShareActionProvider` to function, you must provide it a share intent. This share intent should be the same as described in the Sending [Simple Data to Other Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) lesson, with action `ACTION_SEND` and additional data set via extras like `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.share:

                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBodyText = "Check it out. Your message goes here";
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Sharing Option"));
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used your code the way it is and it didn't work. Maybe there is some error from my side as I am still a beginner in Android and do not understand it well. Can you please tell how exactly I should use your code to work in my code. 
I just used it the way it is in onOptionsItemSelected class.